# How does <%$ %> and <%# %> work in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, webforms-view-engine

I was using ASP.NET Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC for some period of time.

So `<%= %>` in views mean `Response.Write()`, `<%: %>` introduced in MVC adds html escaping.

In SqlDataSource control designer generates something like this `ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FooConnectionString %>"` and in repeater you use `<%# Eval("") %>` sytax.

My question is what exactly do `<%$ %>` and `<%# %>` tags, what methods they traslated into and how do they behave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%$ %>` is the [expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5bd1tad.aspx).

There are some built in shortcuts for AppSettings, Resources and ConnectionStrings. You can also [write your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163849.aspx#S4).

`<%# %>` is the [databinding expression syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx).

This is used in databound controls to resolve property values from the object being bound.

Answer (score 2):

I clipped this text from a book (I can't remember which book) a while ago as I thought it explained the `<%# %>` syntax well -

> Those of you familiar with classic ASP applications might think that
>   the <%# %> syntax looks very familiar. It is similar in purpose, but
>   you need to make sure that you don't confuse the two because doing so
>   could cause your application to function improperly. Whereas in ASP
>   (and ASP.NET), the <%= %> syntax causes whatever is inside the
>   brackets to be evaluated at render time, the <%# %> brackets unique to
>   ASP.NET are evaluated only during binding. As you will see later in
>   this section, the page and each bindable control on the page have a
>   DataBind() method. The expressions contained within the data binding
>   brackets (<%# %>) are evaluated only when the control's DataBind
>   method is invoked.

That only answers half your question, but Rob Stevenson-Leggett's excellent answer covers everything else. I just thought I'd add this by way of some further illustration.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a blog post about the different types of expressions available in ASP.NET Web Forms:

[Expressions vs. Statements, part 2: ASP.NET Code Block Types](https://web.archive.org/web/20130203221323/http://michielvoo.net/blog/expressions-vs-statements-part-2-asp-net-code-block-types/) (internet archive)

It explains the following expression blocks:

`<%$ %>`

ASP.NET Expression Syntax, used to bind against application settings, connection strings, and resources.

`<%# %>`

ASP.NET Data-Binding syntax, only evaluated when calling a data binding method of the control.

`<% %>`

Code blocks, the code becomes part of `RenderMethodDelegate`. The code should be statements. Use `Response.Write` to output something.

`<%= %>`

Same as above, except the code should be a single expression. It will be wrapped in `HtmlTextWrite.Write()`.

Comment: You have removed your article or at least it is no longer there. Also, when _I_ post _just_ a link to an article (as in here) in my website I get abundant criticism.

Comment: I have updated the link and added some information from the original article to the answer.